# Multi level mobile navigation

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, navigation, responsive-design

I'm looking for a way to re-create a main navigation like the one on the mobile/responsive version of the sony site http://www.sony.com/index.php

Anyone know of any plugins that can achieve this? Or even the proper name of this type of navigation set up so I can google it properly.. am having difficulty finding more examples of it around to investigate further

cheers

Comment: Finally! its called a 'Drill Down Menu' - phew! Found a plugin that looks like it'll do the trick here: http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-drill-down-menu-plugin/examples/#